# Как написать функцию для удаления элемента из массива за O(1)?

Tags: javascript

К примеру, имеется такой массив:

```
let library = [
    { id: "4", name: "Name1", author: "Max" },
    { id: "8", name: "Name3", author: "Liza" },
    { id: "3", name: "Name2", author: "Alex" },
    { id: "6", name: "Name2", author: "Ann" }
]
```

И соответственно функция удаления,

```
function deleteEl (id) { 

}
```

она получает id элемента, который необходимо удалить. Если элемент с таким id находился в массиве вернуть true, иначе false.

Comment: в чем сложность?

Comment: за O(1) из массива можно удалить только последний элемент

Comment: Прошу прощения, не понял, что вопрос заключался в удалении за один цикл)
Я имел ввиду, чтоб получить, есть ли вложенный элемент по id:id, подойдет 
`library.some(elem => elem.id === '8')`

А чтоб найти ключ массива и затем его удалить, то
`const elem = library.findIndex((el, index, arr) => (el.id === id) ? index : false )
if (elem) delete library[elem]`
за один проход варианта не знаю(

Answer (score 0):

Никак. Массив - непрерывный участок памяти, а значит при удалении элемента из него надо сдвинуть весь хвост, что даёт линейную асимптотику. За O(1) может работать только `pop`.